# Rails Ajax .post request not running as it should

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, post

Trying to implement a form in a jquery ui dialog. I have a model "Customers", with the standard actions new, create update, etc.

For the "New Customer" link I have a code which loads the form into a modal and then allows me to submit the form via a post request.
Inside the dialog I have a couple buttons to submit form

```
    buttons: {"Save": function() {      
        $.post("/customers", $("#new_customer").serializeArray());
        $(this).dialog('close');},
              "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog('close');}
    }
```

This works fine.

However, when I try to replicate for the Edit link, it doesn't work.

```
    buttons: {"Save": function() {      
        $.post("/customers", $("#edit_customer").serializeArray());
        $(this).dialog('close');},
              "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog('close');}
    }
```

I look at the rake routes at it says:

```
   customers GET    /customers(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"customers"}
             POST   /customers(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"customers"}
```

So, is this because the EDIT doesn't work? Do i need to create a named route for it? Please let me know what you think might be the problem!

My create method looks like this:

```
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    if @customer.save
      redirect_to @customer, :notice => "Successfully created customer."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

In routes.rb i have:

```
   resources :customers do 
     resources :plans
   end
```

and the routes generated are:

```
        customers GET    /customers(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"customers"}
                  POST   /customers(.:format)                             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"customers"}
     new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"customers"}
    edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"customers"}
         customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"customers"}
                  PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"customers"}
```

I have a partial with the form which I load for new and edit methods (the same partial).

```
    <%= form_for @customer do |f| %> 
... 
<% end %>
```

but in the source code it says:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/customers/1" class="edit_customer" id="edit_customer_1" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="DpfK5tChAxY3gOT8CfKQQTS6igRUMAM4tQbCf3GeA8I="></div>
```

So how to I use the PUT from JS?

Thanks!

Comment: in case of edit try changing `$.post` with `$.get`

Comment: it doesn't do anything, it renders on the server, but doesn't edit the object.

Comment: But a POST runs `create`; that's different than `update`, no? What does your `create` method look like?

Comment: Look down into source code, if you have customers as resource, rails automatically generate hidden tag to inform framework that this request is actually PUT.

So you just du $.post, when you serialize your form you should have this hidden name included. Otherwise, just add additional parameter "_method": "put" to submitted params.

Answer (score 0):

If you have customers defined as REST resource:

```
resources :customers
```

then there are two actions defined for your REST controller

```
GET /customers/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
PUT /customers/:id(.:format) {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
```

So try $.get instead of $.post if you want to load customer form, and POST (PUT) to update. 
Since browser don't support PUT method well, Rails emulates this via POST request but inserting hidden into form like `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">`
You don't have to do this if you create your form rails way,

```
form_for(@customer) do |form| ...
```

Then, if you edit existing customer, this tag is automatically inserted, so it will be there if you serialize.

If you don't have REST resource, then you are missing routes. What error do you get?

Comment: how do I do the POST (with hidden PUT) you suggest?

Comment: Thanks Johny, but I'm a bit lost. I've edited the question again, as formatting is coming all wrong now.